# Почему переменная и список обнуляется

Tags: java

```
  else if(call_data1.equals("29")){
                day="29";
            }else if(call_data1.equals("year")){
                year="2016";
            }else if(call_data1.equals("april")){
                month="04";
            }else if(call_data1.equals("day")){
                day="05";
            }
            String date=year+month+day;
            System.out.println(date);
```

есть вот такой кусок кода-когда пользователь шлепает на кнопку в телеграм боте переменной присваевается некоторое значение,вопрос как сделать так,чтбы это значение в этой переменной и оставалось,ДО тех пор,ПОКА пользователь не решит изменить это значение,на данном этапе при нажатии кнопки значение записывается ,по потом пропадает чудесным образом и если пользотватель нажимает другие кнопки не связаные с этой перемной -она пропадает)

Comment: Пытаюсь найти в коде "список". Пока не могу.

Comment: да без разницы ,список ,массив или стек.как вытащить значение переменной .оно имеет значение как только пользватель нажал кнопку.потом он нажимает кнопки другие .которые вобще не связаны с этим блоком и значение обнулятся

Comment: Я Вам сейчас еще один минус поставлю. Что у Вас "обнуляется"?

Comment: есть if(update.hasCallBackQuery),внутри него идет еще три if ,по году ,дате и месяцу.на вроде if(call_data1.equals("30") day=30,сначала пользователь выбирает год и переменной year присваивается значение ,потом выбирает месяц и при присвоении переменной month какого либо значения ,переменная year обнулятся и значение ,значение которое там было каким то образом исчезает.далее я ввоожу date и уже обнулятся month и так по кругу ,воод year обнуляет date

Comment: поправил код для наглядности.,срабатывает условие на year-выводится 2016,потом срабатывает условие на month ,выводит 04,а год то куда делся?

Comment: Мало кода. В этом коде 1) ничего не обнуляется, 2) если выводится 2016, то уже не выведется 04.

Comment: Не может быть за один проход и месяц и год и день. Вот и инициализируется при каждом проходе заново.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорошо. Так и быть. Я угадаю. Вы используете локальные переменные. Сделайте их членами класса.

Comment: переменные вначале метода обьявлены,но горят серым в idea,я их куда не пихал только,ничего не помогает

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав Я не понимаю Вашей терминологии. Что значит "горят серым"? Я уже сказал Вам, что нужно сделать.

Comment: обьявил вначале класса и заработало) спасибо Игорь

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав Уф-ф-ф, здорово! Пожалуйста. Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".