# Поиск пропущеного числа

Tags: алгоритм, математика

есть ряд цифр,например {4,7,6,9,5,x} 
по какой формуле можно найти пропущеное число x=8
ряд может начинаться как с единицы,так и с любого другого положительного числа.
шаг увеличения +1

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922272

Comment: я там все сделал

Comment: Отсортировать и посмотреть на пропуски...

Comment: Наити минимум и максимум. Потом определяем какого промежуточного числа нет. Так?

Comment: формула нужна,как определить какого числа нет?как отсмотреть пропуски? Если начинаестся с единицы там все просто ((n+1)*(n+2)/2)-sum,где n -количество чисел,а sum их сумма

Comment: мне нужно элегантное решение в одну строчку ,а не простыня с ифами .это конкурсное задание .

Comment: Необходимо ограничение, что пропущенное число не является "крайним" в последовательности (либо явное указание, что в этом случае пропущенное число, например, максимально). Без такого ограничения/уточнения задача может иметь два решения. Например, {3,5,4,x} - решения x=2 и x=6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((n+1) * (n+2) / 2) + ((min-1) * (n+1)) - sum,
```

где `n` - количество чисел, `sum` - их сумма, а `min` - минимальное число из данных.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант первый - отсортировать, посмотреть, где соседи отличаются на 2. Если таких нет - значит, пропущено число скраю...

Вариант второй. Найти минимум и максимум, посчитать сумму всех имеющихся чисел и вычесть ее из суммы арифметической прогрессии от минимального до максимального числа с шагом 1. Получим искомое число. Если это 0 - значит, пропущено число скраю...

```
4,7,6,9,5
```

Сортируем:

```
4,5,6,7,9
```

Разность 2 - между 9 и 7, значит - (9+7).2 = 8 :)

```
4,7,6,9,5
```

Минимум - 4, максимум - 9, итого сумма прогрессии - 39, а имеем - 31. Пропущено число 39-31=8 Или - минимум - 4, чисел - 5, значит, сумма должна быть равна (4*2+5)*6/2 = 39...

Comment: скакого? *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor Что - скакого?

Comment: скакого "скраю"?

Comment: А вот это и есть неоднозначность, в рамках поставленной задачи не разрешаемая :)

Comment: сортировать ничего нельзя,скраю число быть не может,так как в таком случае мы физически не сможем узнать сначала оно было пропущено или с конца.есть простая формула без всяких соротировк и поисков максимума ,просто не могу найти ее на просторах интернета

Comment: Вы в школе арифметическую прогрессию учили? Выберите ту формулу, которая вам подходит - по первому и последнему члену, по первому члену, количеству и знаменателю, по последнему члену, количеству и знаменателю - ну неужели же тут надо разжевать арифметику пятого класса?!  если у вас 6,7,9,4,5 - то ведь все равно придется искать или первое, или последнее число (минимум или максимум) - и как вы "без поисков максимума" обойдетесь? все равно нужно будет привязываться к одному из концов. В общем случае меньше O(n) все равно не выйдет.

Comment: Добавлю, что любая формула имеет свои границы (или условия) применимости.