# Как распарсить сложный Json в List

Tags: java, json

От сервера приходит вот такой  json

```
jQuery171010123521258160095_1571660062730({"status":"ok","combinations":[{"barCode":"999859546144","number":"999859546144","numbers":[17,20,31,42,52,2,10,21,30,88,3,44,64,72,83,11,29,48,79,86,24,49,53,61,85,7,15,39,58,78],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999848737003","number":"999848737003","numbers":[7,26,34,79,82,12,31,42,51,69,1,14,23,48,81,10,21,40,58,80,18,29,37,50,68,3,35,62,78,89],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999860332802","number":"999860332802","numbers":[4,25,40,53,90,17,50,67,71,82,18,37,49,69,74,1,15,20,39,54,8,10,46,68,73,33,45,55,79,88],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999860339777","number":"999860339777","numbers":[6,32,66,71,80,2,15,22,35,89,29,48,51,62,74,11,23,31,56,88,10,27,34,49,77,1,44,55,68,86],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999859916773","number":"999859916773","numbers":[16,21,32,67,74,2,35,42,71,83,6,29,47,57,88,23,39,40,54,78,19,28,37,59,63,8,46,60,75,80],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999859234230","number":"999859234230","numbers":[14,31,57,77,82,4,28,30,52,65,2,22,45,67,88,7,10,32,48,51,18,29,39,54,62,26,44,60,74,86],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999848753896","number":"999848753896","numbers":[11,38,55,76,81,19,33,48,62,90,5,28,43,63,79,3,27,64,73,89,6,15,26,36,88,18,32,47,58,67],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999848749752","number":"999848749752","numbers":[39,42,59,69,76,9,13,26,51,81,16,23,32,77,90,5,25,54,70,88,1,17,47,63,85,21,30,43,65,79],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999848765453","number":"999848765453","numbers":[4,17,49,77,83,9,25,31,59,87,11,43,55,69,71,6,12,36,79,84,3,21,32,41,61,24,51,67,78,81],"favouriteNumbers":[]},{"barCode":"999859919264","number":"999859919264","numbers":[23,48,66,78,84,6,17,30,50,87,25,32,58,69,75,19,42,68,71,86,1,11,27,36,51,2,28,39,40,55],"favouriteNumbers":[]}]});
```

мне нужно получит из него List

класс Ticket

```
public class Ticket {
    Long number;

    public Long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Set<Long> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(Set<Long> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    Set<Long> numbers;
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922272/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Распарсить можно ,например, используя json-simple библиотеку.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple111jar.htm

Вы дали json с невалидным форматом.Уберите JQuery...
Вот решение вашей задачи:

```
Вот результат вызова toString() одного обьекта Ticket. 

Ticket [barCode=999859546144, number=999859546144, numbers=[17, 20, 31, 42, 52, 2, 10, 21, 30, 88, 3, 44, 64, 72, 83, 11, 29, 48, 79, 86, 24, 49, 53, 61, 85, 7, 15, 39, 58, 78], favouriteNumbers=[17, 20, 31, 42, 52, 2, 10, 21, 30, 88, 3, 44, 64, 72, 83, 11, 29, 48, 79, 86, 24, 49, 53, 61, 85, 7, 15, 39, 58, 78]]
```

1.Классы

```
Main.java
Parser.java
Ticket.java
```

Их код

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"combinations\":[{\"barCode\":\"999859546144\",\"number\":\"999859546144\",\"numbers\":[17,20,31,42,52,2,10,21,30,88,3,44,64,72,83,11,29,48,79,86,24,49,53,61,85,7,15,39,58,78],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999848737003\",\"number\":\"999848737003\",\"numbers\":[7,26,34,79,82,12,31,42,51,69,1,14,23,48,81,10,21,40,58,80,18,29,37,50,68,3,35,62,78,89],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999860332802\",\"number\":\"999860332802\",\"numbers\":[4,25,40,53,90,17,50,67,71,82,18,37,49,69,74,1,15,20,39,54,8,10,46,68,73,33,45,55,79,88],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999860339777\",\"number\":\"999860339777\",\"numbers\":[6,32,66,71,80,2,15,22,35,89,29,48,51,62,74,11,23,31,56,88,10,27,34,49,77,1,44,55,68,86],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999859916773\",\"number\":\"999859916773\",\"numbers\":[16,21,32,67,74,2,35,42,71,83,6,29,47,57,88,23,39,40,54,78,19,28,37,59,63,8,46,60,75,80],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999859234230\",\"number\":\"999859234230\",\"numbers\":[14,31,57,77,82,4,28,30,52,65,2,22,45,67,88,7,10,32,48,51,18,29,39,54,62,26,44,60,74,86],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999848753896\",\"number\":\"999848753896\",\"numbers\":[11,38,55,76,81,19,33,48,62,90,5,28,43,63,79,3,27,64,73,89,6,15,26,36,88,18,32,47,58,67],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999848749752\",\"number\":\"999848749752\",\"numbers\":[39,42,59,69,76,9,13,26,51,81,16,23,32,77,90,5,25,54,70,88,1,17,47,63,85,21,30,43,65,79],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999848765453\",\"number\":\"999848765453\",\"numbers\":[4,17,49,77,83,9,25,31,59,87,11,43,55,69,71,6,12,36,79,84,3,21,32,41,61,24,51,67,78,81],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]},{\"barCode\":\"999859919264\",\"number\":\"999859919264\",\"numbers\":[23,48,66,78,84,6,17,30,50,87,25,32,58,69,75,19,42,68,71,86,1,11,27,36,51,2,28,39,40,55],\"favouriteNumbers\":[]}]}";
    Parser parser = new Parser(json);
    parser.doParse();
    if (parser.isOk()) {
        List<Ticket> tickets = parser.getResult();
        for (Iterator<Ticket> iterator = tickets.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
    }

}
```

}

Parser.java

```
public class Parser {

private String json;
private boolean isOk;
private List<Ticket> result = new ArrayList<>();

private JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

public Parser(String json) {
    this.json = json;
}

public void setJSON(String json) {
    this.json = json;
    isOk = false;
    result.clear();
}

public void doParse() {
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(json);
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
        String status = (String) jsonObj.get("status");
        switch (status) {
        case "ok":
            isOk = true;
            break;
        default:
            isOk = false;
            break;
        }
        if (!isOk) {
            System.out.println("status is false");
            return;
        }
        JSONArray combinations = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("combinations");
        Iterator combinations_iterator = combinations.iterator();
        Ticket ticket = null;
        while (combinations_iterator.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject tick_obj = (JSONObject) combinations_iterator.next();
            // combinations -> barCode & number
            long barCode = Long.parseLong((String) tick_obj.get("barCode"));
            long number = Long.parseLong((String) tick_obj.get("number"));
            ticket = new Ticket(barCode, number);

            // combinations -> numbers
            JSONArray numbers = (JSONArray) tick_obj.get("numbers");
            Iterator numbers_iterator = numbers.iterator();
            while (numbers_iterator.hasNext()) {
                Long num = (Long) numbers_iterator.next();
                ticket.getNumbers().add(num);
            }
            JSONArray fav_numbers = (JSONArray) tick_obj.get("numbers");
            Iterator fav_numbers_iterator = fav_numbers.iterator();
            while (fav_numbers_iterator.hasNext()) {
                Long num = (Long) fav_numbers_iterator.next();
                ticket.getFavouriteNumbers().add(num);
            }
            result.add(ticket);
        }
    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<Ticket> getResult() {
    return this.result;
}

public boolean isOk() {
    return this.isOk;
}
```

Ticket.java

```
public class Ticket {

private long barCode;
private long number;
private List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Long> favouriteNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

public Ticket(long barCode, long number) {
    this.barCode = barCode;
    this.number = number;
}

public long getBarCode() {
    return barCode;
}

public void setBarCode(long barCode) {
    this.barCode = barCode;
}

public long getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(long number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public List<Long> getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}

public void setNumbers(List<Long> numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
}

public List<Long> getFavouriteNumbers() {
    return favouriteNumbers;
}

public void setFavouriteNumbers(List<Long> favouriteNumbers) {
    this.favouriteNumbers = favouriteNumbers;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Ticket [barCode=" + barCode + ", number=" + number + ", numbers=" + numbers + ", favouriteNumbers="
            + favouriteNumbers + "]";
}
```